# Bessel function and its derivative in a boundary condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, bessel-functions

I have a function $u_{nj}=u_{nj}(r)$ of the radius variable $r$ (cylindrical coordinates) that satisfy the following Bessel equation

$$ r^{2} u''_{nj}+ r u'_{nj} +(k_{nj}^{2}-n^{2})u_{nj}=0, $$

where $n$ is integer, $j$ is the index denoting the $j$-th zero, and the solution must have finite (physical) amplitude everywhere within the domain inside a cylinder of radius $r=a$ (so typically this excludes second-kind Bessel functions and only allows the first kind, $J_{n}$).

This function ($u_{nj}$) also needs to satisfy the following boundary condition at $r=a$

$$ \left[ u_{nj} +(1+i)\beta_{0} a M u'_{nj} \right]_{r=a}=0,  $$

where $\beta_{0}, M, a$ are all constants, and we have $M<<1$ (small).

Somehow the result that satisfies both the equation and boundary condition above turns out to be (after taking first-order approximation in the small parameter $M$) given by

$$ u_{nj}=J_{n}(k_{nj} r), \ \ \ \ \text{where}  \ \ \ k_{nj}=\frac{V_{nj}}{a} [1-(1+i)\beta_{0} M],$$

and $V_{nj}$ denotes the $j$-th zero of the $J_{n}$ function.

I am having difficulty seeing how this result was reached. In particular, how can one attempt to solve an equation of the form

$$\left[ J_{nj} + (\text{constant}) J'_{nj} \right]_{r=a}=0,$$

to reach such result? Am I missing something trivial here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the condition
\begin{equation}
 u_{nj}(a) +(1+i)\beta_{0} a M u'_{nj}(a)=0
\end{equation}
with $u_{nj}=J_{n}(k_{nj} r)$ we must have
\begin{equation}
 J_{n}(k_{nj}a) +(1+i)\beta_{0} k_{nj}a M J'_{n}(k_{nj}a)=0 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
For $M\ll1$, the first term dominates and thus $k_{nj}a\simeq V_{nj}$, where $V_{nj}$ is a zero of $J_n$. To go a step forward, we assume that
\begin{equation}
 k_{nj}a= V_{nj}+\kappa M+o(M)
\end{equation}
This expression and a first order Taylor expansion
\begin{align}
 J_{n}(k_{nj}a)&\sim J_n(V_{nj})+ \kappa M J'_n(V_{nj})\\
 &\sim\kappa M J'_n(V_{nj})
\end{align}
plugged into the condition (\ref{1}) gives,
\begin{equation}
 \kappa M J'_n(V_{nj})+(1+i)\beta_{0} \left(V_{nj}+\kappa M  \right) M J'_{n}(V_{nj}+\kappa M)=0
\end{equation}
or, by keeping the terms up to the first order in $M$,
\begin{equation}
 \kappa M J'_n(V_{nj})+(1+i)\beta_{0} V_{nj} M J'_{n}(V_{nj})=0
\end{equation}
which reads
\begin{equation}
  M J'_n(V_{nj})\left[\kappa+(1+i)\beta_{0}V_{nj}\right]=0
\end{equation}
This condition is fulfilled if
\begin{equation}
 \kappa=-(1+i)\beta_{0} V_{nj}
\end{equation}
We deduce
\begin{equation}
 k_{nj}a\simeq V_{nj}\left( 1- (1+i)\beta_{0}M\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But when you neglected the second term in (1) because $M$ is small, what if $k_{nj} a$ that multiplies it was large?

Comment: Well the second term is not neglected: in the following an expansion in $M$ is done. Only the first order is kept because it corresponds to the answer quoted. If necessary one can expand further. Of course this approximation is accurate if the higher orders are negligible.

Comment: Understood. Brilliant. Many thanks!

Comment: A small question: How can one draw (visualize) the Bessel function when its argument is a complex number? For example here we have $J_{n}(k r)$, where $k$ turned out to be in the complex form $\frac{V_{nj}}{a}(A+iB)$ (with $A,B$ as some constants). How can we visualize this to see how it looks like as a function of $r$? I guess it is not simply a perturbed (shifted) version of $J_{n}$ in terms of the zero location, and maybe it is even different shape because it is now complex (?) Any advice on how to plot or visualize this in a meaningful way to understand it more?

Comment: I don't think that there are simple views in this case. You can have a look at the graphs [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.3.ii). Series expansions near the origin and asymptotic expansion may help to get insights. Additionally, for $\nu>-1$ all zeros of $J_\nu$ are real. BTW, for your initial question, you may also be interested in [this reference](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21.xii).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually trying to plot the vector field whose components are given by our result here, say for $a=1, \beta_0 M=0.01$. I tried to ask this question in another post here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235489/understanding-and-visualizing-bessel-function-with-complex-argument), but I wonder if you can help in this, as you seem to have better understanding of this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Never mind, I just managed to solve it at last! :) Thanks anyway